# jQuery to select div inside div inside form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $form.find()

});
```

```css
#second {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: green;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="first" style="width: 301px; margin:5px 0 0 10px;">
    <div id="second" style="font-size:18px; position: absolute; top: 8px; left: 5px; width: 300px; height: 42px;">Hello</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I want to select the `div` with `id="second"`, in order to change the `background` to `red`. Is there any solution to do that using `find()`.

The most important thing for me is to select that `div` using it's `id`.
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reshadgp/pb9kcscw/)

Comment: Don't hide your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not just do this?

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#second").css("background-color", "red")
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="first" style="width: 301px; margin:5px 0 0 10px;">
    <div id="second" style="font-size:18px; position: absolute; top: 8px; left: 5px; width: 300px; height: 42px;">Hello</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

You can find the element by using `#second` and then change the colour using this. If you want you can bind this to a `click` event, or whatever way you would like to change the `background-color`.

And if you're intent on using `find()` you could do this, and you want to find multiple elements, you could do this

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form").find("#second, #fourth").css( "background-color", "red" );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="first">
    <div id="second">Hello</div>
    <div id="third">World</div>
    <div id="fourth">World</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

You can target as many elements as you want by separating them using a comma.

Comment: but I wanted to use generally, in order to use it in the case of multiple div's.

Comment: @reshad check out updated code. I think the second code snippet is what you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").find( "div#second" ).addClass('red');
});
```

CSS

```
.red{
   background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form div").find( "div" ).css( 'background-color', 'black');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Or as descend of the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").find( "div#second" ).css( 'background-color', 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure of the div id beforehand it would probably be a little redundant using .find() as you could simply use the jquery selector `$("#second")`.

If you wanted to use .find() though you just need to specify where you want the search to begin (the form in your case) and how you want to filter the search

so would be:

```
$("form").find("#second")
```

you could then chain this to `.css()` or add it to a variable or whatever :)